# laravel download file pdf in storage/app/public

Tags: laravel, file, download

Hi i have a pdf file in storage/app/public and i want to download it pressing a button

so i have button in blade

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="planningDwld" data-namefile="{{$planning->file_name}}">
       Scarica planning caricato il 
       {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($planning->date_ins)->format('d/m/Y')}}
       </button>
```

and javascript ajax call

```
  $(document).on("click", '#planningDwld', function(e) {
    $filename = $(this).attr("data-namefile");
    $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: "{{ url('/downloadFile') }}",
    data: {
     'filename': $filename
    },
    success: function(data) {
    }
   }); //fine ajax
```

I ve a function in controller

```
public function downloadFile()
    {
        $filename = request("filename");
        $path = storage_path().'/'.'app'.'/public/';
        $pathToFile = $path.$filename;

        return response()->download($pathToFile);
    }
```

But when i click on the button it doesn't download the file, it only downloads if I click in chrome debug network line where is the function downloadFile and in preview chrome i ve

```
%PDF-1.5
%âãÏÓ
10 0 obj
<</Linearized 1/L 24374/O 12/E 19873/N 1/T 24073/H [ 507 175]>>
endobj
                  
33 0 obj
<</DecodeParms<</Columns 4/Predictor 12>>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<63DA52A9430528F2C6338FF33BE7B657><BC91512376F61B47BFE7E75DF1F5D828>]/Index[10 37]/Info 9 0 R/Length 101/Prev 24074/Root 11 0 R/Size 47/Type/XRef/W[1 2 1]>>stream
hÞbbd``b`š$ü€ãN Á   "äAÄS Áœ"AÜWp±V¶@‚»ÄÒé}béXß@¬@‚u;ˆpl ÂHlÃÀÄÈ0d%#ÄÆw_–pH
endstream
endobj
startxref
0
%%EOF
           
46 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/I 113/L 97/Length 90/S 38>>stream
hÞb``e``òd¯•¨€ˆY8ÅD¡˜a'Ó³d­I+Œ…udþŸ³±ˆic)óEvû'_»ÆÌª†×6’aå#Ÿ‘     À¶Òo
endstream
endobj
11 0 obj
<</Metadata 2 0 R/PageLabels 6 0 R/Pages 8 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj ........ETC.....
```

Why?I tried also to defined headers but don't work
Thanks

**EDIT**

My only solution is without using javascript ajax call but just do in html blade

```
   <a href="https://example.com/drh/downloadFile?filename={{$planning->file_name}}" 
    class="btn btn-primary"> Scarica planning caricato il 
    {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($planning->date_ins)->format('d/m/Y')}}</a>
```

and in controller just this

```
   public function downloadFile()
    {
        $filename = request("filename");
        return response()->download(storage_path("app/public/{$filename}"));
    }
```

Comment: I think your call is not accurate, according to Laravel documentation you should call directly`return Storage::download($filename);`
Obviously, you need to use the storage facade in your controller, as `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`

Comment: ok i did it but it tells me File not found at path: home2/wlimaser/public_html/drh/storage/app/public/Planning_7597.pdf but it is there! Why it cannot see it?

Comment: Have you linked the storage to the public disk ?

Comment: as Tithira said, you have to run `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: yes i did it but dont work :(